# how to login in drupal admin using Linux root user access to the server?

Tags: linux, drupal

The Drupal admin account credentials aren't working on my staging/development server.I have only Linux root user access to the server.What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not allready have drush, install it, then go in app directory and type : drush uli 1, it will generate a one time login link for user with uid 1 (=admin) wich you just need to copy paste in your browser and then you will be connected and can change the password.